# Is it realistic for Beck to chew out Roman in the beginning of The Negotiator?

Tags: analysis, realism, the-negotiator

[*The Negotiator* (1998)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120768/) begins with a short hostage situation unrelated to the film's main plot. Once the crisis is resolved, the lead tactical cop (Beck / Morse) chastises the hostage negotiator (Roman / Jackson) for exposing himself to danger. Isn't that the exact opposite of what would happen?

The hostage taker, Omar, has a shotgun pointed at the head of his estranged wife's daughter, and demands that the police bring his wife to the scene. Roman eventually concludes he won't be able to persuade Omar to put the gun down, and that it'll be necessary to shoot Omar.

It's obviously really dangerous to do that while Omar's shotgun is inches from the girl's head. So, Roman lies that the wife has arrived, and says he needs to inspect Omar's apartment before the police will allow her in.

Roman enters the apartment, manipulates Omar into a different room where he's in the police snipers' crosshairs, and then signals the sniper when it's time to incapacitate Omar. Roman even grabs Omar's shotgun and has it pointed at Omar's head *before Omar's body hits the ground* (judging by the frame-by-frame).

Later that evening at the bar where the police are celebrating the successful resolution of the crisis, Beck corners him and says this:

> Despite how things worked out today, you put these guys [the other police] in jeopardy. If you were taken hostage if would have fucked up everything.

This strikes me as an absurd thing to say. At least in the movies (and I'm thinking of the rest of the hostage genre), the police will always choose replace a civilian hostage with a police hostage if that's the only way to remove the civilian from danger. The reasons for preferring that trade are obvious:

1. Police explicitly volunteer for dangerous work, while civilians do not
2. Police have defensive training (and, often, equipment) that civilians do not
3. Police almost always use a police hostage as an opportunity to smuggle things and information in and out of the hostage-taker's domain, often successfully

And, at least in this case, it seems clear that Omar is not capable of threatening more than one person at a time, since he's working alone and has only a single, semi-automatic weapon.

So, is it realistic that Beck would be upset with Roman for deliberately inserting himself into the hostage situation? Wouldn't he actually be pleased, particularly because Roman's plan made use of Beck's team (along the lines of *Henry V's* St Crispin's Day speech)?

Answer (score 1):

I always thought of it as a bit of foreshadowing, since later on Beck gives the command to breach the building and 2 of his unit are taken hostage.  it sort of built up tension between Beck and Roman, that tension was escalated when Sabian came onto the scene, and then there was a sort of "gotcha" for the audience when Beck gets relieved of duty.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely establishes that there's tension between the two men specifically, and between the two resolution strategies generally. I assume that is 100% the reason it's in the movie. That's why I'm asking: I suspect the writer built this piece of the foundation on sand. Was hoping for a reality-check.